# Assistance with BASH script for OpenWRT firewall to execute a command if ping response / latency is high

Tags: bash, openwrt, openvpn

Looking for some greatly appreciated help writing a bash script on OpenWRT. I want the script to check ping response times for an OpenVPN connection and if the response time in ms goes over a certain threshold to then perform an action such as change the configuration file to connect to a different OpenVPN server. I will set the script up via crontab on the OpenWRT firewall.

So far I have worked out the command to get the ping result in ms that I need for the query.

```
ping -c 1 1.1.1.1 |  awk 'FNR == 2 { print $(NF-1) }' | cut -d'=' -f2
```

This will ping the IP address (in this instance Cloudfare DNS) and print the ping ms time to the screen.

I can also modify this command to write the value to a file instead by using stdbuf

```
ping -c 1 1.1.1.1 |  awk 'FNR == 2 { print $(NF-1) }' | stdbuf -o0 cut -d'=' -f2 > pingms
```

I need some help on then taking this value either via stdout or output to a text file and performing an action if the value is greater than say 100ms.

eg. if value is greater than 100ms (from command above) then execute additional command / script, otherwise do nothing

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please edit the post to clarify and narrow down the question? What is something you've already tried, and what is the error you're seeing, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ $(ping -c 1 1.1.1.1 |  awk 'FNR == 2 { print $(NF-1) }' | stdbuf -o0 cut -d'=' -f2 ) -gt 100 ]; then
  echo "greater than 100 do something!"
else
  echo 'less than 100 nothing to do, bye...'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, on OpenWRT you will not have a `BASH` shell, rather a shell with "limitations", i.e. `ash`. Also `stdbuf` is normally not part of the official builds and `busybox`, and various shell/architecture combinations are handling floats differently, so I recommend to cut the fraction to keep your script architecture- and build-independent. I hope the following oneliner will help you out.

```
[ $(ping -c1 1.1.1.1 | awk 'FNR == 2 { print $(NF-1) }' | cut -d'=' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1) -gt 100 ] && echo "GT 100" || echo "LT 100"
```